# Null Pointer Exception using Spring Boot service as a dependency in a batch job

Tags: spring-boot, jar, dependencies, program-entry-point, autowired

I'm re-using an old, standalone AWT-based Java class which backs up and restores mysql databases.

One thing it needs to do is decrypt a password that it reads from a properties file.

The logic for this is contained in a Spring Boot application.

I'm instantiating the encryption service and decryptor in the standalone class as follows:

```
DecryptionService decryptionService = new DecryptionService();
```

The decryptionService uses the @AutoWired annotation to create a decryptor:

```
@Autowired
private IRSADecryptor decryptor;
```

For now, I'm running it Eclipse from the same project as the service.

When I try to decrypt the password as follows:

```
    String decryptedPassword = decryptionService.decryptTextUsingProductKeys("abc");
```

the debugger show the decryptionService is null.

Here are the first few lines of the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ap.services.decryption.service.DecryptionService.decryptTextUsingProductKeys(DecryptionService.java:21)
    at com.ilcore.util.SosaMaintenanceJFrame.jButtonDatabaseBackupActionPerformed(SosaMaintenanceJFrame.java:529)
    at com.ilcore.util.SosaMaintenanceJFrame$6.actionPerformed(SosaMaintenanceJFrame.java:207)
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not going about this the right way, but I'd like to not have to import the decryption logic. What are my options?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your dependency injection issues?

Comment: Yes, actually what I needed to instantiate was the decryptor inside the decryption service.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept is a a correct answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Autowired` annotation will not create your decryptor object, but will try to locate a `Bean` of that type and inject it in your `DecryptionService`. This means that you should not use a constructor to instantiate your `DecryptionService`. The `DecryptionService` should be defined as a `@Service` and injected in another component (`@Component`, `@Controller` etc.), from where you will invoke the specific methods for decrypting your data.

Comment: Thanks. For history, I did instantiate it, but this helped.